# How to use array of images with pictureBox and hscrollbar to scroll between the images?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In Form1 I have in the designer a pictureBox.
Then I added a timer in the tick event i did:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (savedall == true) {
    for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++) {

    }
  }
}
```

And the hscrollbar scroll event:

```
private void hScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e) {

}
```

When the savedall is true then I want to be able to scroll between all the images in filePaths and display each image in the pictureBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepare the list of images and a `scrollbar imgScroller` like this:

```
List<string> imageList = new List<string>();

imageList = Directory.GetFiles("d:\\", "*.jpg").ToList();

imgScroller.Minimum = 0;
imgScroller.Value = 0;
imgScroller.Maximum = imageList.Count - 1;
imgScroller.SmallChange = 1;
imgScroller.LargeChange = 1;
```

And the code the `Scroll` event like this:

```
private void imgScroller_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    if (scrolledPB.Image != null) scrolledPB.Image.Dispose();

    int index =  (int)imgScroller.Value;
    scrolledPB.Image = Image.FromFile(imageList[index]);
    someLabel.Text = "Displaying image " + index + " of " + imageList.Count - 1;
}
```

Not sure what the timer is doing or if you already have the file paths..